# Getting file details

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, file-io, file-attributes

I'm trying to get file details from pictures and videos such as width and height without having to actually open the file in vb.net. I plan on indexing a lot of files at once so if I could just grab the file details like the ones in a files properties menu that would help a lot. I know they are labeled differently for different files. Some are width and height, some are frame width and frame height.

Whenever I try to find information about this it always involves loading the file as a bitmap. I don't want to have to load potentially thousands of images and videos. Surely there is a way to just read the file details?

Comment: So, you have open file sequentially to read the header info ..

Comment: I doubt this metadata is stored anywhere "outside" the file.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Implementing this kind of functionality for every possible combination of media format and container under the sun would be a project by itself. Instead I'd recommend using MediaInfo, which is an open-source project designed to do exactly that.

A quick google search for a VB.NET wrapper around the MediaInfo library came up with this: http://teejeetech.blogspot.be/2013/01/mediainfo-wrapper-for-net-projects.html

Good luck!